# object properties is null after ajax callback in asp.net webmethod

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, ajax, webforms

**this is not asp.net mvc, this is asp.net webforms**

I am trying to send object literal like this

```
templateProperties = {}
```

and my ajax call like this

```
$.ajax({
    beforeSend:updateTemplateProperties,
    type: "POST",
    url: templatePropertiesUpdateUrl,
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: JSON.stringify({ "templateProperties": templateProperties }),
}).done(function (data) {
    log(data.d);
});
```

I am calling function before sending:

```
updateTemplateProperties = function () {

    templateProperties.NameFont = "qwq";
    templateProperties.NameBold = true;
    templateProperties.NameItalic = false;
    templateProperties.NameFontColor = "#FFF";
    templateProperties.NamePositionX = 52;
    templateProperties.NamePositionY = 896;
    templateProperties.NameSize = 23;

    templateProperties.DateFont = "ssda";
    templateProperties.DateBold = false;
    templateProperties.DateItalic = true;
    templateProperties.DateFontColor = "#EEE";
    templateProperties.DatePositionX = 47;
    templateProperties.DatePositionY = 236;
    templateProperties.DateSize = 12;

}
```

adn My webmethod is like that

```
[WebMethod]
public static string UpdateTemplateProperties(TemplateProperties templateProperties)
{
    var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    return serializer.Serialize(templateProperties);
}
```

and this is my TemplateProperties class

```
[Serializable]
public class TemplateProperties
{
    public  string NameFont { get; set; }
    public  string NameBold { get; set; }
    public  string NameItalic { get; set; }
    public  string NameFontColor { get; set; }
    public  string NamePositionX { get; set; }
    public  string NamePositionY { get; set; }
    public  string NameSize { get; set; }

    public  string DateFont { get; set; }
    public  string DateBold { get; set; }
    public  string DateItalic { get; set; }
    public  string DateFontColor { get; set; }
    public  string DatePositionX { get; set; }
    public  string DatePositionY { get; set; }
    public  string DateSize { get; set; }
}
```

when checking templateProperties I found the entire object properties equal to null

```
{"NameFont":null,"NameBold":null,"NameItalic":null,"NameFontColor":null,"NamePositionX":null,"NamePositionY":null,"NameSize":null,"DateFont":null,"DateBold":null,"DateItalic":null,"DateFontColor":null,"DatePositionX":null,"DatePositionY":null,"DateSize":null}
```

I am not getting any error from this call, and I have tried everything I know but it is not working
normally I pass the parameters individually to the webmethod one by one but this time they are too much to do so , So I want to send the whole object as one entity

Comment: When , where and how did you check the templateProperties? Try posting your code more cohesively, since the order of operations is fairly important to your issue.

Comment: 1: in the console in the browser debugging tools,2: in the debugging mode in visual studio 3: this is all the code!

Comment: That doesn't tell me *which* `templateProperties` was null, but I think I have an idea what the issue is, anyway.

Comment: please read the question to the end, I have posted the return from the ajax call at the end of my question. also this is the same in the debugging mode in visual studio

Comment: @sacho where is the answer that you have just added!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason the `beforeSend` callback function `updateTemplateProperties` is called but the `templateProperties` is not being initialized correctly before sending the data, I just call the `updateTemplateProperties` function before beginning the ajax call and it is working now, but I really don't know why it is not working this way